# Forwarding a specific email address

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, email, pop3

We have a server running Windows 2003 with IIS SMTP installed for sending emails and POP3 Service to receive emails. We would now like to forward one of the email accounts (support@myDomain.com) to a completely new mail address hosted on another server/domain.

It doesn't seem like POP3 service has any forwarding capabilities (or any capabilities for that matter :-) ).

Please suggest on how I can solve this. A really neat bonus would be if the "forward" was transparent, ie the users should not be able to (easily) see that the email was forwarded.

*[Picture of POP server]*
http://www.designerline.se/db/pop3service.png

Big Thanks
//David

Comment: "POP3 service" isn't clear enough.  What *software* are you using to receive emails?  Exchange?  Dovecote?  Gordano?

Comment: Oh, Microsoft's POP3 Service...  didn't even know they had that...

Comment: Microsoft POP3 Service

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much of an answer, but it might get you started:

Googling "microsoft pop3 service create alias" came up with some [sketchy documentation on using the software,](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/0/1/501d7556-4c8d-4f41-bcd0-223be197a503/Advmail.doc) including instructions on creating an alias.  (Which is what you're asking to do.)

Comment: From what I understand of the documentation, an *alias* can only forward to another address on the same server. But maybe I misunderstood? Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

See the blue for incoming mail and orange for outgoing:

[image: simple email flow diagram]

SMTP is where you need the redirection to happen, as it's the mail transport protocol. Pop3 is just for the email client to see what email is waiting for it, and only comes into play after email has been delivered, too late to be redirected properly.

I don't know if / how you can do what you want with the setup you have, but one option is to change to use something like [MailEnable](http://mailenable.com/standard_edition.asp) - it's a Windows email server, and the standard edition is free for commercial use.